# export states of child function to set in other functional component

Tags: reactjs

```js
fun1 (){
  
  fun 2(){
  const [state1,setState1] = useState({})
  }
  
 export setState1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

}
```

I want export setState1 to use in other component

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are fun1 and fun2? If there are regular functions you can't do something like that, as the reactjs docs say on the hooks rules page (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

#### Only Call Hooks at the Top Level

**Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns.

#### Only Call Hooks from React Functions

**Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions**. Instead, you can:

- Call Hooks from React function components.
- Call Hooks from custom Hooks.